# Position:Sticky text element with vertical text

Tags: css, css-position, sticky

I am hoping for a CSS-only solution to having a vertical piece of text stuck to a set of elements next to it.  The problem seems to be either at the beginning (it creates a bunch of white space, but then abides by the top and bottom of the parent element:

https://jsfiddle.net/h24ab1e9/

[image: White space because of text height]

OR, if I use something like `transform:rotate` or negative margins, or something along those lines, the height of the text is not calculated correctly and it scrolls well beyond the parent element.

https://jsfiddle.net/h24ab1e9/1/

```
h2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  left:32px;
  /* rotate: 90deg; */
  transform-origin: top left;
  /* transform: translate(0,-100%); */
  font-weight: 900;
  /* width: 0; */
  /* height: 0; */
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;  
}
```

I've tried no height, no width, negative margins, rotate, transform, writing-mode, and combinations of all the in between.  Is is possible to have vertical oriented text that can be `position:sticky` correctly within a parent, while starting at the top and stopping at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

Your white space is created by the `top: 120px` and the `margin: 120 0` styles. If you remove those and instead use another element as a spacer it works as intended.

```css
section {
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #000;
}

.row {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  padding-left:120px;
}

.item {
  width:100%;
  height:360px;
  background:blue;
}

.item:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background:green;
}

h2 {
  position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left:32px;
    /* rotate: 90deg; */
    transform-origin: top left;
    /* transform: translate(0,-100%); */
    font-weight: 900;
    /* width: 0; */
    /* height: 0; */
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. Some filler text. </p>
  <h2>MY STICKY WORDS! THESE ARE LONG!</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The white space I am referring to is not those.  The vertical text and the "items" (blue/green blocks) are meant to be aligned next to one another.  In the first JSFiddle, the there is a tremendous amount of white space next to the text before that happens.  In the next JSFiddle, they are aligned next to each other, but because I am "rotating" the element, it's height is incorrect and therefor is scrolls beyond the parent. I updated my Q with picture for reference.  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: For what it's worth, I realized wrapping the element in a container and making that sticky was the key to accomplishing this task.  Probably delete the question soon.  I appreciate your help!  https://jsfiddle.net/d2pbosk6/

Comment: Your image helps a lot. Glad you found something that works!